# How to create a "Subscribe to Calendar" link to an ics file that works on Google Calendar on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have a web app that creates custom ics files that users can then subscribe to via a link to the file. On OS X and iOS, iCal handles the ics file and asks if the user would like to subscribe to the calendar. On desktop Google Calendar (in-browser), I can use the following format:

https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=http://example.com/calendarfile.ics

However, on Android, opening this link gives me the following:

"You are trying to use the desktop version of Google Calendar from a mobile browser. Some features may not work correctly. Would you like to proceed to the desktop version anyway?"

How can I structure the link so that on Android it will automatically open the Calendar app and allow the user to subscribe - or alternately, open the mobile calendar and allow the user to subscribe without throwing an alert first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it's currently not possible to subscribe to ics files on Android. You can download the file and import it to the calendar app (but it will not auto refresh).